# SSIS ( SQL Server Integration Services ) & Teradata Volatile Tables . ( Teradata SQL tuning )

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, teradata, database-tuning

I would like to understand what Modalities  SQL server Integration service  ( SSIS )  uses to connect to Teradata 14

- ODBC
- .NEt
- OLE DB

These ones or more / less than these.  My main question is HOW do I    IMPLEMENT teradata volatile table create syntax in SSIS Package.    Which of these above support it and how is it done ? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a sql task, you could use a [global temporary table](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1093_111A/ch02.021.14.html) . That way you still have a session specific temp table, but you don't have to create it on the fly.

Comment: The DBA's geniuses  don't give any temp space to these SSIS Users. My Only bet is VT or rewrite the Query directly .

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't it be as easy as an SQL task with the table sql?

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE table_1
(
column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
.
.
columnN datatype
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: Question was will SSIS ALLOW the create volatile table statement. Remember I am asking this to be done THROUGH  a 3rd Party tool NOT directly using SQL assistant.  Of course you can write the code that way. My question was exe. it via SSIS. I DONT have SSIS and I am working with a team that uses SSIS to access TD and  I want to know how I can get them to implement VT .Does that make it clear ?